# Chrome dev tools replaces link tags by style tags

Tags: css, html, google-chrome-devtools

I am experiencing a weired issue with the Chrome Dev Tools :

- In the web application I'm developing, the CSS **link** tags in the HTML header are transformed in **style** when displayed in the **elements tab** of the CDT
- On other websites, link tags are correctly displayed in CTD.

**Example :**

- In the HTML (with `ctrl+u`) I get that:

`<link href="./style/css/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="./style/css/lib/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

- In the element tab of the CDT I get that:
  [image: Link html tag transformed in style by chrome dev tools]

This is a big issue for me because I can't link the style to the local files if it is not included with the link tag.

So the question is: Why is it happening ? and how can I force CDT to interpret the style through the original link tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours of research, I found that the library prefixfree (http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) was responsible of that.

It takes the CSS from linked files, modifies it and finally put it back in a script tag.

Comment: UGH. Same issue. Thanks for figuring it out. I'd rather just write my own vendor prefixes than ruin my ability to use the web inspector.